# counting how many of aspei object is in an array list

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm currently working on a program that wants you to store objects into an array list. I'm new to java and not quite sure how i can  count how many of a specific object there is in an array list example being you have a university class then you add a student into an array list named people. you can also add  staff and  faculty objects. anyways i need to calculate how many student objects in the array list as well as how many staff and faculty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `List<Object>` containing these objects and `Student`, `Staff` and `Faulty` classes, you can just loop through the array and use the `instanceof` operator to see if the current item is of the Student, Staff of Faculty object type - then just increment the relevant `int` counter.